How to get the id of the current tab?
tabpagenr returns the index of the current tab, but I want an ID instead.
I’m trying to make a custom tab name plugin (or rather, extend Win tabs) where I can manually set the tab name to something explicit. I would do this if I had a tab ID by having a dictionary from tab ID to name
tabpagenr is not sufficient because if someone closes a window, the indexes will change

There is no tab id. There is no api that requires/accepts/returns anything, except tab number.
To track any info related to specific tab make use of tab-local variable(s). If you only need custom names for tabs then you won't need any numeric id nor global dictionary. Just tab-local string.
